# Открытие всплывающей формы по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, форма

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть всплывающая форма, которую нужно запустить по нажатию на ссылку, я не знаю как это записать в html документе, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

JS код(нашел в инете):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Обработка по клику              
$('a.popup').click(function() {                             
    // Переменная для хранения атрибута rel нажатой ссылки
    var popupid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#' + popupid).fadeIn();
    // Добавим div fade вниз тэга body
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=30%)'}).fadeIn();
    // По центру
    var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
    var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;
    // выравнивания модального окна по центру
    $('#' + popupid).css({
    'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
    'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
    });
    document.forms.registration.reset();
});

// Переключение на основное окно
$('#fade').click(function() {
    $('#fade , #popuprel').fadeOut()
    return false;
    });
});

Форма

<form class="popupbox" id="popuprel" name="registration">
</form>
<div id="fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что именно вам надо записать в html документе? Этот код? Тогда оберните в тэги <script>, библиотеку поключите выше этого блока. В общем, примерно следующее:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // тут весь ваш JS код
</script>
<head>
```

**UPD**

1. В ссылке, по которой должно открываться форма, добавляем атрибут **rel**, значение которого, должно быть id-шником формы, которая будет в модальном окне.
2. Так же не забываем в эту ссылку добавить класс **popup**
3. Добавляем "отмену обычного поведения" ссылки

   ```
   $('a.popup').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // и т.д.
   ```

[Смотрим пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/KNxg8/2/)

Comment: нет,мне нужно запустить данный код по нажатию на ссылку

Comment: @Petr, разместите ваш код на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) и ссылку на него - в студию. У меня с телепатией плохо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KNxg8/

Comment: вот, все сделал

Comment: @Petr, Смотрите апдейт в ответе

Comment: большое спасибо, все работает.